# Не работает одна из форм отправки

Tags: javascript, php, html, веб-программирование, email

Имеется данный код, но одна из форм отправки не работает. Что надо исправить, чтобы обе формы работали корректно?

```
<form id="contacts__form">
       <div class="home-container03">
                <span class="home-text09 lng-more">Свяжитесь с нами</span>
                <input
                  type="name"
                  placeholder="Name"
                  name="name"
                  class="home-textinput input"
                 required/>
                <input
                  type="tel"
                  placeholder="Phone"
                  name="tel"
                  class="home-textinput1 input"
                  required
                />
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Question..."
                  name="massage"
                  class="home-textinput2 input"
                />
                <button type="submit" class="home-button ">
                  <span class="home-text10 lng-contact">Обратиться к нам</span>
                </button>
            </div>
          </form>        



<form id="contacts__form">

<div class="contacts__massage" 
            style=" display: none;
            align-items: center;
            border: solid 1px #ddd;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            flex-direction: column;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            z-index: 10;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 20px;
            text-align: center;">
              <img src="./public/good.svg" alt="Сообщение" width="40px">
              <p class="contacts__info" 
              style="font-size: 16px;
              font-weight: 600;
              color: #000000;
              margin-bottom: 0;">
                Ваша заявка принята!
              </p>
              <p class="contacts__info-text" style="font-size: 14px;
              color: #000000; 
              margin-bottom: 0;">
                В ближайшее время мы с Вами свяжемся!
              </p>
            </div>
              <div class="home-container58">
                  <span class="home-text86 lng-write">Напишите нам</span>
                  <input
                    type="name"
                    placeholder="Name"
                    name="name"
                    class="home-textinput input"
                   required/>
                  <input
                    type="tel"
                    placeholder="Phone"
                    name="tel"
                    class="home-textinput1 input"
                    required
                  />
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Question..."
                    name="massage"
                    class="home-textinput2 input"
                  />
                  <button type="submit" class="home-button ">
                    <span class="home-text10 lng-contactus">Обратиться к нам</span>
                  </button>
              </div>
            </form>
```

```
$(function() {

    /* Отправка заявки */
    $("#contacts__form").submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "post.php",
            data: $(this).serialize()
        }).done(function() { //Если все хорошо, показываем сообщение об отправки и очищаем поля
            $(".contacts__massage").addClass("active").css('display', 'flex').hide().fadeIn(); 
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                jQuery("#contacts__form").trigger("reset"); 
                $(".contacts__massage").removeClass('active').fadeOut(); 
            }, 3000); 
        });
        return false;
    });


    /*Маска для инпута*/
     var telInp = $('input[type="tel"]');
     telInp.each(function(){
        $(this).mask("+7 (999) 999-99-99");
     });

});
```

```
<?php

$recepient = "ror.dym@mail.ru"; //Почта куда будут приходить письма
$subject = "Заявка с сайта ERCKAP"; //Сообщение
$headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"; 
$headers .= "From: test.ru <test.ru>\r\n"; 

$name = trim($_POST["name"]);
$phone = trim($_POST["tel"]);
$massage = trim($_POST["massage"]); //Поля

$message = "Имя: $name <br/> Телефон: $phone <br/> Сообщение: $massage";

mail($recepient, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

```
/*
    jQuery Masked Input Plugin
    Copyright (c) 2007 - 2015 Josh Bush (digitalbush.com)
    Licensed under the MIT license (http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/#license)
    Version: 1.4.1
*/
!function(a){"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["jquery"],a):a("object"==typeof exports?require("jquery"):jQuery)}(function(a){var b,c=navigator.userAgent,d=/iphone/i.test(c),e=/chrome/i.test(c),f=/android/i.test(c);a.mask={definitions:{9:"[0-9]",a:"[A-Za-z]","*":"[A-Za-z0-9]"},autoclear:!0,dataName:"rawMaskFn",placeholder:"_"},a.fn.extend({caret:function(a,b){var c;if(0!==this.length&&!this.is(":hidden"))return"number"==typeof a?(b="number"==typeof b?b:a,this.each(function(){this.setSelectionRange?this.setSelectionRange(a,b):this.createTextRange&&(c=this.createTextRange(),c.collapse(!0),c.moveEnd("character",b),c.moveStart("character",a),c.select())})):(this[0].setSelectionRange?(a=this[0].selectionStart,b=this[0].selectionEnd):document.selection&&document.selection.createRange&&(c=document.selection.createRange(),a=0-c.duplicate().moveStart("character",-1e5),b=a+c.text.length),{begin:a,end:b})},unmask:function(){return this.trigger("unmask")},mask:function(c,g){var h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o;if(!c&&this.length>0){h=a(this[0]);var p=h.data(a.mask.dataName);return p?p():void 0}return g=a.extend({autoclear:a.mask.autoclear,placeholder:a.mask.placeholder,completed:null},g),i=a.mask.definitions,j=[],k=n=c.length,l=null,a.each(c.split(""),function(a,b){"?"==b?(n--,k=a):i[b]?(j.push(new RegExp(i[b])),null===l&&(l=j.length-1),k>a&&(m=j.length-1)):j.push(null)}),this.trigger("unmask").each(function(){function h(){if(g.completed){for(var a=l;m>=a;a++)if(j[a]&&C[a]===p(a))return;g.completed.call(B)}}function p(a){return g.placeholder.charAt(a<g.placeholder.length?a:0)}function q(a){for(;++a<n&&!j[a];);return a}function r(a){for(;--a>=0&&!j[a];);return a}function s(a,b){var c,d;if(!(0>a)){for(c=a,d=q(b);n>c;c++)if(j[c]){if(!(n>d&&j[c].test(C[d])))break;C[c]=C[d],C[d]=p(d),d=q(d)}z(),B.caret(Math.max(l,a))}}function t(a){var b,c,d,e;for(b=a,c=p(a);n>b;b++)if(j[b]){if(d=q(b),e=C[b],C[b]=c,!(n>d&&j[d].test(e)))break;c=e}}function u(){var a=B.val(),b=B.caret();if(o&&o.length&&o.length>a.length){for(A(!0);b.begin>0&&!j[b.begin-1];)b.begin--;if(0===b.begin)for(;b.begin<l&&!j[b.begin];)b.begin++;B.caret(b.begin,b.begin)}else{for(A(!0);b.begin<n&&!j[b.begin];)b.begin++;B.caret(b.begin,b.begin)}h()}function v(){A(),B.val()!=E&&B.change()}function w(a){if(!B.prop("readonly")){var b,c,e,f=a.which||a.keyCode;o=B.val(),8===f||46===f||d&&127===f?(b=B.caret(),c=b.begin,e=b.end,e-c===0&&(c=46!==f?r(c):e=q(c-1),e=46===f?q(e):e),y(c,e),s(c,e-1),a.preventDefault()):13===f?v.call(this,a):27===f&&(B.val(E),B.caret(0,A()),a.preventDefault())}}function x(b){if(!B.prop("readonly")){var c,d,e,g=b.which||b.keyCode,i=B.caret();if(!(b.ctrlKey||b.altKey||b.metaKey||32>g)&&g&&13!==g){if(i.end-i.begin!==0&&(y(i.begin,i.end),s(i.begin,i.end-1)),c=q(i.begin-1),n>c&&(d=String.fromCharCode(g),j[c].test(d))){if(t(c),C[c]=d,z(),e=q(c),f){var k=function(){a.proxy(a.fn.caret,B,e)()};setTimeout(k,0)}else B.caret(e);i.begin<=m&&h()}b.preventDefault()}}}function y(a,b){var c;for(c=a;b>c&&n>c;c++)j[c]&&(C[c]=p(c))}function z(){B.val(C.join(""))}function A(a){var b,c,d,e=B.val(),f=-1;for(b=0,d=0;n>b;b++)if(j[b]){for(C[b]=p(b);d++<e.length;)if(c=e.charAt(d-1),j[b].test(c)){C[b]=c,f=b;break}if(d>e.length){y(b+1,n);break}}else C[b]===e.charAt(d)&&d++,k>b&&(f=b);return a?z():k>f+1?g.autoclear||C.join("")===D?(B.val()&&B.val(""),y(0,n)):z():(z(),B.val(B.val().substring(0,f+1))),k?b:l}var B=a(this),C=a.map(c.split(""),function(a,b){return"?"!=a?i[a]?p(b):a:void 0}),D=C.join(""),E=B.val();B.data(a.mask.dataName,function(){return a.map(C,function(a,b){return j[b]&&a!=p(b)?a:null}).join("")}),B.one("unmask",function(){B.off(".mask").removeData(a.mask.dataName)}).on("focus.mask",function(){if(!B.prop("readonly")){clearTimeout(b);var a;E=B.val(),a=A(),b=setTimeout(function(){B.get(0)===document.activeElement&&(z(),a==c.replace("?","").length?B.caret(0,a):B.caret(a))},10)}}).on("blur.mask",v).on("keydown.mask",w).on("keypress.mask",x).on("input.mask paste.mask",function(){B.prop("readonly")||setTimeout(function(){var a=A(!0);B.caret(a),h()},0)}),e&&f&&B.off("input.mask").on("input.mask",u),A()})}})});
```

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Судя по коду, он ни к одной форме не применяется, так как здесь нет ни одной формы с ID `contacts__form`.

Comment: Немного не тот код, добавил, исправил, айдишники у обоих одинаковые, но работает только первый

Comment: ID должен быть уникальным на странице, он не может быть одинаковым для разных элементов, это не класс. Используйте класс вместо ID, в таком случае.